# what will be the result if i reallocating the calloc pointer?

Tags: c, dynamic-memory-allocation, realloc

```
int main()
{
  int *ptr = (int*)calloc(10,sizeof(int));//allocating memory for 10 integers
  ptr = realloc(ptr,20*sizeof(int)); //reallocating the memory for 20 integers
  free(ptr);
  return 0;
}
```

Initially the ptr hold memory contains zeros,but the newly created memory contains zeros or garbage values.

> > If zeros present how can realloc know weather the ptr is created using malloc or calloc.

Comment: The code is not correct. Read the man-page of `realloc` (that will also answer your question). You are expected to show at least _some_ effort on your own.

Comment: oh now this it correct. Time to update my answer :)

Comment: I must say I find that hard to follow. But since OP actually improves the typos, I gladly do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even if you called `realloc` properly like (without casting the result and assigning it back or it doesn't work properly):

```
ptr = realloc(ptr,20*sizeof(int));
```

(and some may say that it's not safe as `realloc` can return `NULL` thus losing the ref to `ptr`)

it doesn't. It just reallocates *without* setting the rest to `0`

You have to set the rest of the memory to 0 manually using `memset` for instance.

I would do:

```
int *ptr_new = realloc(ptr,20*sizeof(int));
if (ptr_new == NULL) { /* print error, free(ptr) and exit: no more memory */ }
else
 {
    // set the end of memory to 0
    memset(ptr_new+10,0,sizeof(int)*10);
   ...
```

Note: a common mistake is *not* assigning back the result of `realloc` since it seems to work, up to the point where the OS needs to move the memory to another block, in that case your `ptr` pointer becomes invalid and you have undefined behaviour.

Comment: Won't `realloc` copy over the data that was at the pointer previously (as much as fits, that is)? In that case, the 0s would persist, at most the same amount you had before.

Comment: but if we contain some data in our ptr, and then realloc it, the realloc will copy the data in the new place, am I right??

Comment: yes, they would persist, but not above the previously allocated memory size.

Comment: `realloc` tries to avoid moving the original memory if a contiguous zone can be found. If not, it moves the existing memory into a bigger area.